# Cannot find PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_CONSENT in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, android-bluetooth

I have faced with issue that when pairing request happens I got the following `PairingParams.PAIRING_VARIANT_CONSENT` (= 3) pairing variant, but it is absent in ...

```cs
object obj = intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
BluetoothDevice device = (obj as BluetoothDevice)!;
var extraPairingVariant = intent.GetIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraPairingVariant, 0);
switch (extraPairingVariant)
{
  case BluetoothDevice.PairingVariantPin:
  {
    ...
  }
    break;
  case BluetoothDevice.PairingVariantPasskeyConfirmation:
  {
    ...
  }
    break;
  case \* 3, what constant should be here ?? *\
  {
    ...
  }
    break;
}
```

... `BluetoothDevice` do not contain the something like `PAIRING_VARIANT_CONSENT` ...

Does somebody faced with the same issue ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I call `abortBroadcast()` to not show the pin dialog but only if the `BluetoothDevice.ExtraPairingVariant` is not `3`. Otherwise a dialog must be shown for the user to accept the pairing. This state occurs when you remove the already paired device and ask to pair it again. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/bluetooth/PairingParams.html#pairing_variant_consent)

```
BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice)intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
if (action == BluetoothDevice.ActionPairingRequest)
        {
            device.SetPin(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("####"));
            int exraPairingVariant = intent.GetIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraPairingVariant, 0);
            if (exraPairingVariant == BluetoothDevice.PairingVariantPasskeyConfirmation || exraPairingVariant == BluetoothDevice.PairingVariantPin)
            {
                InvokeAbortBroadcast();
            }
        }
```